# How do I change the current working directory of a Python program to the user's home directory?

Tags: python, chdir

I'm in python 3.7.3 on MacOS 10.14.5.
I found the os.chdir() to change the programs working directory.  Now I need to learn how to access the current user's environment variables such as $HOME.

One contributor said that user.info contains the home directory, but I haven't found how to obtain that.  Thank you.

These don't work:  :-)

```
os.chdir("$HOME")
os.chdir("~")

os.chdir("$HOME")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$HOME'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME` and `~` are shell syntax that expands into the user's home directory, not actual directory names by themselves.

Use `os.environ` to access environment variables in Python:

```
os.chdir(os.environ['HOME'])
```

Comment: PERFECT, exactly what I was looking for.  Much thanks.  I'll study os.environ more now.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~"))
```

The function `os.path.expanduser` replaces the tilde with the user directory and works on Unix/Linux and Windows